# Creating conditional Apollo Client RefetchQueries parameter in Angular applications

Tags: angular, graphql, observable, client, apollo

I have a component and this component needs to run different refetchQuery and navigate when coming from 3 different pages of the application. For this, I listen to the appState data published in the application layer. I am using Apollo Client package in my Angular application to manage GraphQL operations. I tried to manage these operations with the route state that came with Angular before, but it was a bit complicated and difficult to manage for me. I found a nice solution and wanted to share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

appState is the application status service published in the entire application. Important data between components is exchanged here. An observable pattern.

The refetchHandler method creates a refetchQueries directory based on the appState status, whichever lazy loaded page module is coming from.
Likewise, navigateHandler points to the previous operation page to go to after adding a position.

```js
refetchHander(appState: AppState): MutationBaseOptions {
    const refetchQueries = [
        {
            query: this.coordinatesTableGQL.document,
            variables: {
                filter: {
                    skip: 0,
                    take: 10,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            query: this.coordinatesCountGQL.document,
            variables: {
                filter: {
                    skip: 0,
                    take: 10,
                },
            },
        },
    ] as any;

    if (appState?.request) {
        refetchQueries?.push({
            query: this.requestDetailGQL.document,
            variables: {
                id: appState.request.id,
            },
        });
    }

    if (appState?.activity) {
        refetchQueries?.push({
            query: this.activityDetailGQL.document,
            variables: {
                id: appState.activity.id,
            },
        });
    }

    return {
        refetchQueries,
    };
}

navigateHandler(appState: AppState): void {
    if(appState.request) {
    this.router.navigate(['requests/detail', appState.request?.id]);
}
if (appState.activity) {
    this.router.navigate(['activity-detail', appState.activity?.id]);
}
this.router.navigate(['coordinates']);
    }

createCoordinate(): void {
    this.isProgress = true;
    let createCoordinateInput: CreateCoordinateInput;
    if(this.appState.activity?.id) {
    createCoordinateInput = {
        ...this.coordinateForm.value,
        activityId: this.appState.activity?.id,
    };
} else {
    createCoordinateInput = this.coordinateForm.value;
}
const options = this.refetchHander(this.appState);
this.createCoordinateSub = this.coordinateService.create(createCoordinateInput, options).subscribe({
    next: createCoordinate => {
        this.isProgress = false;
        this.snackBarService.success(`${createCoordinate.title} coordinate added!`);
        this.appStateService.removeMarkers();
        this.navigateHandler(this.appState);
    },
    error: (error: Error) => {
        this.isProgress = false;
        this.alertBoxService.error({ message: error.message });
    },
});

}
```